# Last offset in partition not readable

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm processing a compacted Kafka Topic to extract all messages at a given time for which no tombstone was sent to the topic.
Therefore at process startup I determine the endOffset for all partitions and process records until I reached or exceeded the endOffset-1.
Sometimes this job hangs, because it's unable to reach the endOffset-1.

My topic description:

```
PARTITION     OLDEST_OFFSET     NEWEST_OFFSET     EMPTY     LEADER                                                                REPLICAS     IN_SYNC_REPLICAS
0             0                 2808              false     b1.com     1,2          1,2
1             0                 1754              false     b1.com     1,3          1,3
2             0                 2745              false     b2.com     2,3          2,3
3             0                 2763              false     b2.com     2,3          2,3
```

Now for partition 3 all consumers can read up to offset 2761. The 2762 can not be fetched, and it does not give any error for a broken message.

I've tried with different consumer toolings to access message at offset 2762 and I'm unable to identify what is located there.

Once I produce a new message to partition 3 (moving the endOffset to 2764) I'm able to consume until offset 2763 while consumers are just skipping offset 2762.

Is there any possibility to find out what exactly is the issue with Offset 2762 (in my case)?

I'm not using transactions, so this is not a transaction fencing message.

**EDIT**: Found the issue, some part of the application used transactions on that topic in rare cases. Changing ConsumerConfig to read_committed gives correct LSO on endOffsets() call.